# How can I alter the CSS of an element that is not being shown as a component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to change the css proprieties of an element that does not have a component by itself. Let me explain:

I have this line:

`<CanvasImage className="CanvasImage" id="CanvasImage" />`

Now, on the element inspector I get this:

```
<div class="CanvasImage sc-eXNvrr hJEowj" id="CanvasImage">
↓ I want to edit the line right below this comment ↓
<canvas width="1952" height="1002" style="width: 976px; height: 501px;"></canvas>
↑ This is what I want to edit ↑
</div>
```

The thing is that the only component I got is the one I told you before, how can I achieve this? I've tried to change the CSS of the component but the image is not being affected at all.

**CSS**

```
const CanvasImage = styled.div`
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  (I want to add "border-radius 8px;" but does not work when I put it here!)
`;
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Can you include your relevant CSS code?

Comment: Have you tried targeting `#CanvasImage canvas { ... }`? Show your CSS please.

Comment: Is the `CanvasImage` component written by you or is it from some library? If not, can't you just select the `canvas` in CSS via `#CanvasImage canvas{...}`? (Edit: Damn, too slow)

Comment: Just updated the CSS, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `canvas { ... }` to your styled div.
So your code should look like this:

```
const CanvasImage = styled.div`
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  canvas {
    border-radius 8px;
  }
`;
```

For more info check out [this](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting)